# How to disable button in an if condition

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, button

How do i disable a button if the prod_quantity == 0?

```
<?php
    $prod_qty = $row['prod_quantity'];

            if ($prod_qty == '0'){
                echo "<h1>sold out</h1>";
            }
?>
```

and here is the button that i need to be disabled when prod_qty == 0

```
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row["prod_id"]?>)" />
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add an `if` condition to the button to set the property as `disabled` if `$prod_qty == '0'` like shown below :

```
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" <?php if ($prod_qty == '0'){ ?> disabled <?php   } ?> onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row["prod_id"]?>)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($prod_qty==0)
{
     <?php
     <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" disabled />
     <?php
}
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" 
  <?php if($row["prod_qty"]==0) 
  {
     echo ' onclick="addtocart('.$row["prod_id"].')" ';
  }
  else
  {
       echo ' disabled=disabled ';
  }
?>
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$prod_qty = $row['prod_quantity'];

        if ($prod_qty == '0'){
            echo "<h1>sold out</h1>";
            echo '
                <input 
                    type="button" 
                    value="Add to Cart" 
                    onclick="addtocart('.$row['prod_id'].')" 
                    disabled
                />'
        }else{
            <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row["prod_id"]?>)" />
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

javascript onclick function...

```
function addtocart(prod_qty){
    var quantity=parseInt(prod_qty);
    if (quantity == 0){
         document.getElementById("addtocartButton").disabled = true;   
    }

}
```

your button

```
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="addtocartButton" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row["prod_id"]?>)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $prod_qty = $row['prod_quantity'];

            if ($prod_qty == '0'){
                echo "<h1>sold out</h1>";
            }
?>

<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row["prod_id"]?>)" {{($prod_quantity == 0) ? 'disabled' : ''}} />
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes